# pandas way to get incremented count of occurrences

Tags: python, pandas

I made the following code

```
df['C'] = 1
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if (df.loc[i-1, 'A'] == df.loc[i, 'A']) and (df.loc[i-1, 'B'] == df.loc[i, 'B']):
        df.loc[i,'C'] = df.loc[i-1,'C'] + 1
```

in order to fill a new column, 'C' in this way

```
    A   B           C
0   a   unico       1
1   b   unico       1
2   c   repetido    1
3   c   repetido    2
4   c   repetido    3
5   d   unico       1
6   e   repetido    1
7   e   repetido    2
8   f   unico       1
```

And I was wondering if there is a pandas method to do this without the for loop.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [GroupBy.cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) like this:

initial df:

```
+----+----+----------+
|    | A  |    B     |
+----+----+----------+
| 0  | a  | unico    |
| 1  | b  | unico    |
| 2  | c  | repetido |
| 3  | c  | repetido |
| 4  | c  | repetido |
| 5  | d  | unico    |
| 6  | e  | repetido |
| 7  | e  | repetido |
| 8  | f  | unico    |
+----+----+----------+
```

```
df['C']=df.groupby(['A', 'B']).cumcount()+1
```

Output:

```
+----+----+-----------+---+
|    | A  |    B      | C |
+----+----+-----------+---+
| 0  | a  | unico     | 1 |
| 1  | b  | unico     | 1 |
| 2  | c  | repetido  | 1 |
| 3  | c  | repetido  | 2 |
| 4  | c  | repetido  | 3 |
| 5  | d  | unico     | 1 |
| 6  | e  | repetido  | 1 |
| 7  | e  | repetido  | 2 |
| 8  | f  | unico     | 1 |
+----+----+-----------+---+
```